# How to calculate this standard normal probability and also chisquared?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

X is standard normal. I want to know

$$\frac{d}{dz}P(-\sqrt{z} \leq X \leq \sqrt{z})$$

I don't know how to do that. The answer should be the pdf of chi-squared (1) distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Write your function as a difference of CDF evaluating at two different points. Then differentiate.

Also, you should know that $F'(z)=f(z)$ where $F$ is the CDF and $f$ the PDF.

---

Notes.

$$
P(-\sqrt{z}\le X\le \sqrt{z})=P(X\le \sqrt{z})-P(X\le -\sqrt{z})=F(\sqrt{z})-F(-\sqrt{z})
$$

Now use the chain rule.

Comment: I don't know the CDF of normal distribution. I only know the pdf of standard normal distribution. I can write an integral which endpoints are +- sqrt(z)

Comment: @christine: you only need the "definition" of CDF.